# How can I access the browser API in a React firefox extension sidebar?

Tags: reactjs, firefox-addon

I'm re-writing an extension for firefox that has a sidebar. The previous version didn't use React for the sidebar, and this new version does. In the old version, the sidebar html includes a vanilla js script, and that script uses the browser API, particularly:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((m) => {});
```

A separate content script uses browser.runtime.sendMessage.. for example, if the user copies a selection, the selected text gets sent as a message to the sidebar, which then uses it to populate a form in the sidebar. All of this works great.

The new sidebar is react. When I use browser.runtime or any part of the browser API, React wont compile. "'browser' is undefined'"

I've tried:

- Putting calls to browser in their own functions, and importing them from their own files.
- Adding them to index.js outside of the call to reactDOM.render thinking i may be able to pass it as a prop.

I've pored through React docs, looking for any mention of working with the browser API and found nothing. I've read every article and tutorial about creating extensions with React, and haven't found a single one that accesses the browser API.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something. I linked a separate js file with a script tag (from index.html in public), and that file listens for messages on browser.runtime, then dispatches a CustomEvent for the react app to listen for:

index.html:

```
...
        <script src="browser.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

browser.js:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
    if (msg.name == "url") {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("url", { detail: msg.data }));
    }
});
```

react component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("url", (e) => {
            setUrl(e.detail);
        });

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("url", (e) => {
                setUrl(e.detail);
            });
        };
    }, []);
```